# Mysql query don't get first row in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I trying to get the latest orders in my database and show in php frontend.
The problem is when i print the data, the first element in the array is not appear.

Example code

```php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myDatabase";
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$counter = 0;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `supplier` = '".session('email')."' ORDER BY `id_order` DESC";
if ($result = $db->query($query)){
    if($result->num_rows > 0) { 

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $ordersArray = array();

        // Set orders data to ordersArray 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $name = $row["name"];
            $orderID = $row["id_order"];

            $ordersArray[] = array('id_order'=> $orderID,
                                    'name'=> $name, );
        }
        foreach($ordersArray as $row){
            if( $counter <= 4 ){
                echo ($row["name"]);
                echo ($row["id_order"]);
                $counter = $counter + 1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo ('<tr><td>No tienes ordenes recientes</td></tr>');
    }
}
$db->close();
```

Example output

```
4
3
2
1
```

I have a fifth value in the database that should be displayed first, but it does not appear

Comment: you probably want to prove that (not just to us, but to yourself): what happens if you run the same query in the mysql REPL? Because it's a good bet it finds four rows, not five, and what you think should be a match is probably something silly like "off by one letter" or the like.

Comment: I tried that, mysql show me 5 rows

Comment: Then _definitely_ prove that by showing the _actual_ query that gets sent to mysql by PHP, and then copy-paste the console output that you get when you run that query in the mysql REPL. Because otherwise you're just asking people to guess what's wrong. Remember to add all the details necessary for people to understand your question to your post, as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: that is the problem, the array show me all rows except the first

Comment: Is the line being lost in the first call to `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch the first row already before the while loop starts...

```
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // << first row feteched here
    $ordersArray = array();

    // Set orders data to ordersArray 
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the random fetch:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Making this call moves the result pointer up but you're not adding this row to `$ordersArray`.

Alternatively, if for some reason you do need to access the first row outside your `while` loop, either add the data to the new array or use `$result->data_seek(0)` to reset the pointer.